# ejs remove line break between td elements in for loop

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to render the `<th>` in for loop, the content in the th is the variable. But when the HTML is rendered, there are many line breaks between each `<th>`. I am not asking how to remove the variable line break using <% -%> trim mode.

```
  <thead>
     <th class="yellow-field"></th>
      <% blockUnitDetail.UnitArr.forEach(unit=>{ %>
         <th class="yellow-field"><%= unit %></th>
      <% }) %>
  </thead>
```

HTML:

```
 <thead>
      <th class="yellow-field"></th>
        
      <th class="yellow-field">A1</th>
        
      <th class="yellow-field">A2</th>
        
      <th class="yellow-field">A3</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The control flow code `if else ...`  will occupy the one line in the HTML. So should use the Whitespace-trim mode (slurp all whitespace) for control flow with <%_ _%>

```
  <thead>
        <th class="yellow-field"></th>
        <%_ blockUnitDetail.UnitArr.forEach(unit=>{ _%>
            <th class="yellow-field"><%= unit %></th>
        <%_ }) _%>
  </thead>
```